# How to use macvim to ssh into a headless server

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, vim, macvim

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5

I installed macvim for the first time in my life.

I enjoyed using MacVim I was wondering how to SSH from it into a headless server within the MacVim itself.

Currently, I used a terminal to SSH into the headless server while writing code in my MacVim.

I was wondering if there's a way I can just MacVim to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set in your .vimrc:

```
set nocp
filetype plugin on
```

save and exit.

Restart vim and enter:

```
:e scp://user@host//path/to/file
```

The system will prompt you for the user's password. And you're in.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try this later. If it works exactly as expected, will mark as answer. Thanks!~

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [conque](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) that allows you to run a shell or other command in a Vim buffer. It hasn't been updated since 2011, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in netrw plugin:

```
:e scp://user:pass@host//path/to/dir/
:e scp://user:pass@host//path/to/dir/file
```

See `:help netrw`.

You can also use Vim on the remote host in your terminal.